# Convert from a fixed-sized c_char array to CString

Tags: rust, ffi

My FFI binding returns a struct with fixed-size `c_char` arrays, and I would like to turn those into `std::ffi::CString` or `std::String`.

It looks like the `CString::new` function coerces the pointer to a vector.

```
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct FFIStruct {
    pub Id: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 256usize],
    pub Description: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 256usize],
}

fn get_struct() -> Option<FFIStruct> {
    println!("cheating");
    None
}

pub fn main() {
    match get_struct() {
        Some(thing) => 
            println!("Got id:{}",CString::new(thing.Id.as_ptr())),

        None => (),
    }
}
```

Here is the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Affi%3A%3ACString%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aos%3A%3Araw%3A%3Ac_char%3B%0A%0A%23%5Brepr(C)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20FFIStruct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20Id%3A%20%5B%3A%3Astd%3A%3Aos%3A%3Araw%3A%3Ac_char%3B%20256usize%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20Description%3A%20%5B%3A%3Astd%3A%3Aos%3A%3Araw%3A%3Ac_char%3B%20256usize%5D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afn%20get_struct()%20-%3E%20Option%3CFFIStruct%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22cheating%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20None%0A%7D%0Apub%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20get_struct()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(thing)%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Got%20id%3A%7B%7D%22%2CCString%3A%3Anew(thing.Id.as_ptr()))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0) link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C strings that you don't own should be translated using `CStr`, not `CString`. You can then convert it into an owned representation (`CString`) or convert it into a `String`:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;

pub fn main() {
    let id = [0 as c_char; 256];
    let rust_id = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(id.as_ptr()) };
    let rust_id = rust_id.to_owned();
    println!("{:?}", rust_id);
}
```

You should also use the `libc` crate for types like `c_char`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this kind of solution:

```
fn zascii(slice: &[c_char]) -> String {
  String::from_iter(slice.iter().take_while(|c| **c != 0).map(|c| *c as u8 as char))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create std::ffi::CStr from a pointer but you have to use unsafe keyword.Like this

```
use std::ffi::CStr;
//use std::os::raw::c_char;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct FFIStruct {
    pub id: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 256usize],
    pub description: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 256usize],
}


fn get_struct() -> Option<FFIStruct> {
    println!("cheating");
    None
}
pub fn main() {
    match get_struct() {
        Some(thing) => 
            println!("Got id:{:?}",unsafe{CStr::from_ptr(thing.id.as_ptr())}),

        None => (),
    }
}
```

you can also convert CStr into String by using this method

```
CStr::from_ptr(thing.id.as_ptr()).to_string_lossy()
```